# Charting the value of Datomic facts over time

Tags: charts, datomic

Since Datomic stores assertions and retractions of facts, is it possible to use this built-in storage to chart changes to a value over time, e.g. a price history?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The command you want is [datomic.api/history](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/index.html#datomic.api/history).

Called with a database value, it returns a special db featuring all datom additions and retractions.

```
(ns datomic-history-demo.core
  (:require [datomic.api :as d :refer [db q]]))

(defn demonstrate []
  (let [db-uri '"datomic:mem://fnord"]
    (d/delete-database db-uri)
    (d/create-database db-uri)
    (let [conn (d/connect db-uri)]

      (d/transact conn [{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
                         :db/ident :demo/amount
                         :db/valueType :db.type/long
                         :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
                         :db/doc "An interesting quantity."
                         :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}])

      (let [tempid (dbg (d/tempid :db.part/user))
            tx-data @(d/transact conn [{:db/id tempid
                                       :db/doc "initial value"
                                       :demo/amount 5}])
            id (dbg (d/resolve-tempid (:db-after tx-data) (:tempids tx-data) tempid))]

        @(d/transact conn [{:db/id id
                            :db/doc "subsequent value"
                            :demo/amount 17}])

        @(d/transact conn [{:db/id id
                            :db/doc "final value"
                            :demo/amount 23}])

        (let [special-history-db (d/history (db conn))]
          (->>  (q '[:find ?instant ?e ?amount ?operation
                     :where
                     [?e :demo/amount ?amount ?tx ?operation]
                     [?tx :db/txInstant ?instant]]
                   special-history-db)
                (sort-by first)))))))

(demonstrate)

(comment
  ;; evaluates to
  ([#inst "2014-02-25T19:12:24.054-00:00" 17592186045418 5 true]
   [#inst "2014-02-25T19:12:24.058-00:00" 17592186045418 5 false]
   [#inst "2014-02-25T19:12:24.058-00:00" 17592186045418 17 true]
   [#inst "2014-02-25T19:12:24.062-00:00" 17592186045418 23 true]
   [#inst "2014-02-25T19:12:24.062-00:00" 17592186045418 17 false])
```

Comment: Maybe add a retraction to the demo as well and show the evolution of one and the same entity? Now you use three different entities.

Comment: @MichielBorkent Whoops, you're right! Thanks for pointing that out.  Fixed.